# How to use a modal window in titanium?

Tags: mobile, window, modal-dialog, titanium, appcelerator

i have a serious problem here. i'm trying to use a modal window in my application. till now i used just a window over the parent window. but this caused a problem of not disabling the background.

here is my window:

[image]

the problem in the above pic is the background is not being disabled. if i use the modal window it occupies the whole view, which i dont want.

What i'm need of:

[image]

i need a view something like this alert view, which wen shown the background goes to disable mode.

any help is highly appreciated..

thank you...

Comment: I don't see the image. Please provide some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately You can not use the modal window as dialog box, but you can do a small trick and make your window look like a modal window.
Create a view and disable the click event on it. Add your dialog window to this view and show this view on screen.

```
 var disableView = Titanium.UI.createView({
            height:480,
            width:320,
            top:0,
            backgroundColor:'#000',
            opacity:0.7,
            touchEnabled:true
        });

 disableView.add( yourWindow);
```